# How to parse Java code stored in a string

Tags: java

How can I parse Java code stored in a String?

Example:

```
String s = "int i = 2; System.out.println(\"the number is: \" + i);";
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Do You want to execute the code in the String ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Groovy!

```
String s = "int i = 2; System.out.println(\"the number is: \" + i);";
Binding binding = new Binding();
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);
Object value = shell.evaluate(s);
```

Answer (score 3):

You would probably try to use the [`JavaCompiler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) interface...

Search for `JavaCompiler` and `ToolProvider` (which is what you typically use to get hold of an instance of the interface) for tutorials etc.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative could be the [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/)